# Long to wide with a character twist

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape, data-manipulation

I have a problem that looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301778/r-reshape-data-long-to-wide-with-unknown-number-of-columns) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39411038/r-count-of-strings-by-two-factors) but I cannot get what I am after.

I have the following sample dataset:

```
country_code=c('USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','CHN','CHN','CHN','CHN','CHN','CHN')
target_var=c('V1','V1','V1'  ,'V2'  ,'V2' ,'V2' ,'V1' ,'V1' ,'V1','V2' ,'V2' ,'V2')
VAR=       c('X7','X8','X140','X114','X18','X28','X29','X22','X2','X22','X23','X24')
Ranking=   c(1   ,2.5 ,2.5   ,1.5   ,1.5  ,1.5  , 1   ,2    ,3   ,1.5  ,1.5  ,3)
df<-data.frame(country_code,target_var,VAR,Ranking)
```

And I need to convert from a long to wide format for all combinations of country_code and target_var. The twist I was referring to is that I only want to retain the top X VARs by Ranking (let's say 2 for this example), retaining the ties. So the end result of the example dataset will look like:

Please note that for USA the "ties" are retained so instead of the top 2 I get the top 3. The ties could have occurred in CHN instead.

[image]

I have tried with a nested loop and rbind, but I am not able to make it work. I also looked at a number of threads re long to wide but the vast majority only "reshape" numbers, not characters, which is what the VARs are. I suspect a dplyr solution is what would make sense but I can't get it work. Thank you

Comment: Try `df %>% group_by(country_code, target_var) %>% top_n(2, wt = Ranking)  %>% mutate(n = row_number()) %>% select(-Ranking) %>% spread(n, VAR)`

Comment: You might want to add this as a solution....!! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `top_n` to subset the rows, and then `spread` from 'long' to 'wide'

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(country_code, target_var) %>% 
  top_n(2, wt = Ranking) %>%
  mutate(n = row_number()) %>% 
  select(-Ranking) %>% 
  spread(n, VAR, sep="")
```